# Count the number of occurence per column with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, missing-data

I want to count the number of occurrences per column of two different values the first one is the number of null and the second one is the number of `\N` in my dataframe. Example I've got:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   D
1  \N  1   \N  12  1    
2  4       \N  3   0   \N
3      4   M       \N  1
```

I'm expected the following result:

```
A  2
B  1
C  2
D  1
E  1
F  2
```

I already succeed to count the number of missing value with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("mypath/myFile", sep=',')
null_value = df.isnull().sum()
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
break_line = df[df == '\N'].count()
return break_line + null_value
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: Could not compare ['\N'] with block values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one liner:

```
ns = df.applymap(lambda x: x == '\N').sum(axis = 0)

 null_value + ns

A    2
B    1
C    2
D    1
E    1
F    2
```

Comment: You were slightly faster; however, I think transposing is not necessary: you can just use `sum()`.

Comment: you're right, I had transposed as I was trying another way before but there's no need.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only want to count values where the string ends with '\N'.  If not, you can use `str.contains` instead.

I use a dictionary comprehension to loop through the columns of the dataframe and a vectorized `str` function to count the number of rows with `\N` at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['\N', 4, None], 
                   'B': [1, None, 4], 
                   'C': ['\N', '\N', 'M'], 
                   'D': [12, 3, None], 
                   'E': [1, 0, '\N'], 
                   'F': [None, '\N', 1]})

>>> df
      A   B   C   D   E     F
0    \N   1  \N  12   1  None
1     4 NaN  \N   3   0    \N
2  None   4   M NaN  \N     1    

>>> pd.Series({col: df[col].str.endswith('\N').sum() 
               if df[col].dtype == 'object' else 0 
               for col in df}) + df.isnull().sum()
A    2
B    1
C    2
D    1
E    1
F    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That output differs from the desired one. You will have to add the NaNs to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following using [applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x == '\N').sum() + df.isnull().sum()
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
A      2
B      1
C      2
D      1
E      1
F      2
dtype: int64
```

Note: You use `D` twice; I now replaced that by `F`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which uses only vectorized calculations:

```
df.isna().sum() + (df == '\\N').sum()
```

Output:

```
A    2
B    1
C    2
D    1
E    1
F    2
```